# How can i add inline onclick event to hyper links using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to generate nearly 80 hyperlinks using jQuery. I did that, all are fine. Now my client wants me to add a click event on to the hyperlinks? How can i do that?

my present link is :

```
<a href="#" class="removed purchase-btn">Long Sleeve Breton Top</a>
```

but i need to add this :

```
$('<a onclick="site.exec('page', 'openInternal', {'url': 'http://www.site.in/en-GB/Products/quickshop.aspx?qsi=AM154YEL&amp;});"  href="#">link'+i+'</a>').appendTo('#hello');
  }
```

for that, i used this function but there is no use:

```
$(function (){

  for(i=0;i<80;i++){
    $('<a onclick="site.exec('page', 'openInternal', {'url': 'http://www.site.in/en-GB/Products/quickshop.aspx?qsi=AM154YEL&amp;});"  href="#">link'+i+'</a>').appendTo('#hello');
  }

})
```

But it's not working. Any ideas to make this work?

This links i need to generate and put in to application. so directly a click event from jquery i can't use. Strictly i need to place this code in inline..

Comment: Use [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 0):

Use an event handler instead of inline code

```
$(function (){
  var parent = $("#hello");  //Get the element that will hold all the links.

  for(var i=0;i<80;i++){
      parent.append("<a href='http://www.site.in/en-GB/Products/quickshop.aspx?qsi=AM154YEL&amp;'>link"+i+"</a>");
      //Append a link with the URL in its href attribute
   }

    parent.on("click", "a", function(e) { //Select links under the #hello element and provide a click handler
        site.exec('page', 'openInternal', {
            'url': this.href //Use the href property of the link
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //Don't follow the href link
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
$("a.removed").live("click", function(){
    //do something
});
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, and was frowned upon even before that. I think this type of binding is better than `.click()` for the purpose, but `.on()` should be the function used (or `.delegate()` prior to 1.7).

Answer (score 0):

If your hyperlinks are wrapped in another div then :

```
$("#divid a").each().click(function(){

    ......

});
```

or

```
$("a").each().click(function(){

    ......

});
```

Improving it further according to your requirement may solve your problem.

EDIT: wrapped selector in quotes

Comment: and remomber quotes around edit: `$("a").click(function() {...`

Comment: @AndreasAL sorry, forgot in a hurry... thanx btw:)